Command-line option to disable too many processes in htop
By default, htop shows many more processes than other tools (top, ps). The solution is to press H, as mentionned in Why are there many processes listed under the same title in htop?, to get the "usual" shorter process list.
With which command-line argument should we run htop, to have this behaviour?

In Debian htop saves its config in ~/.config/htop/htoprc and the state of H is there as hide_userland_threads=1 or hide_userland_threads=0. No matter what htop shows "by default", it's enough to configure it once and the setting will be saved. Doesn't your htop save the setting?

@KamilMaciorowski it does, but each time I deploy a new VM, I don't want to reconfigure this, I would prefer to copy/paste a command-line command.

@Basj I have a base copy of my .toprc that I copy around for the same reason. Once you have enough such utilities and custom configurations, it makes more sense to copy the config files around instead of random command-line arguments

@muru is there an encoding problem in this file? Here is how it looks on Github: https://i.sstatic.net/AR95Ze8J.png

It's a binary file, top doesn't save it's configuration as text. GitHub is vainly trying to interpret it as text.

@muru Good to know! That is a strange choice from the developers of top to use a binary format for a configuration file... I don't see the benefit in doing this. Here it seems to be correctly displayed: https://github.com/TheJJ/conffiles/blob/master/.toprc, but still with a few non-ascii characters. Developers of top, why? ;)

There's pretty much how mine shows up in less, but because of those binary fields, the encoding detection gets messed up (e.g., file .toprc identifies mine as ISO-8859 text)

There is no command-line option in htop to do this, not even an undocumented option.
As noted by Kamil Maciorowski, if you start htop once, toggle the display of threads (H), and exit, the setting is stored in htop’s configuration file and subsequent htop invocations will use the same setting. The configuration file is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/htop/htoprc (~/.config/htop/htoprc); writing hide_userland_threads=0 there before the first execution of htop will achieve the desired effect.
